# CISCO PACKET TRACER "INVALID IP ADDRESS"

Tags: cisco, networking, packet-tracer

Hi I am still new and studying about networks have here 234.1.18.6/29 address and mask but when I try it out on Packet tracer it gets me an invalid message. I cannot understand why this address are invalid.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid address is correct: `234.1.18.6` is not a unicast but a multicast address from `224.0.0.0/4`. It cannot be used as an interface/source address.

For an interface in a private network you should use an address from RFC 1918 (`10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, `192.168.0.0/16`).