# Cisco Packet Tracer gives "Invalid IP Address" when I assign an address to a router

Tags: cisco, router, ip, network, packet-tracer

I was given an exercise where I have an IP address range and I have to configure multiple sub networks from that range. The address is `238.61.192.128` with the mask `255.255.255.128 (/25)`. I created my first subnet (on paper). It has 32 addresses and it goes from `238.61.192.128` to `238.61.192.159` (so the mask is `255.255.255.224 (/27)`). Then I tried to assign the first usable address (`238.61.192.129`) to a router (in Cisco Packet Tracer), but no matter what I do, I get an 'Invalid IP Address' error from Packet Tracer. I tried everything, I even tried changing the ports from FastEthernet to Gigabit and the other way around, I thought that might have something to do with it, but nothing seemed to work. Even if I try to create a subnet which just links 2 routers (so no PCs involved) it still doesn't allow me to use that address, I get the same error. I read [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/cisco-packet-tracer-invalid-ip-address) that the range I was given is actually a class D range, so I cannot use it for my purposes (if I understood that question and answer correctly). But how come that exercise gave me this IP range? Is the exercise incorrect? Or can I do something to use that IP range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses from 224.0.0.0/4 are *multicast addresses*. They cannot be used as source address or for unicast.

Unless you actually own the IP address range you might want to stick to RFC 1918 private addresses: 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12 and 10.0.0.0/8.

Comment: So it's possible that the exercise is incorrect. If I use an address outside the D class (so not from `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`) it works.

Comment: If the exercise explicitly requires that address than it's invalid. Note that all *educational, certification and homework questions* are off-topic here, see the [help].